# Is it possible to negotiate the position rank in an UK academic job offer?

Tags: job-search, negotiation

I received a job offer from a UK university. The post was for a senior lecturer/reader position. When the Head of School called me, he hinted that they would offer me a reader position. But two days later when I received the written offer, they actually give me a senior lecturer position with the highest point. I was a bit disappointed as I expected it was a reader position. I have no experience in UK academic system (I am currently working in the US), but I heard there is little room to negotiate in the UK system. I am wondering if I can negotiate for a higher rank (reader) without insulting them. Besides I am going to interview for a reader position with another school. If I get the 2nd offer, can I ask the 1st to match (based on the UK academic culture)? Thanks for your input in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that they are different ranks. At some UK universities they are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I researched their system. Senior lecturer is on the point scale 37-48, and reader is 46-56. So they actually made an offer at the critical point and it was said in the letter that promotion to reader with depend on performance.

Comment: Ask for readership. It's not insulting, it's ambitious. You can also bargain based upon your 2nd offer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can *always* ask about salary and position for any job you are applying to. They won't stop considering you because you asked for more money.

While we are researchers, and love what we do [citation needed], in our society we need money and work for money*, thus bringing money to the negotiations is (or should be) an obvious part of the "finding a job" process.

They can say "yes", "let's negotiate" or "no". Just be prepared for all, and make the decision as you see fit.

*you wouldn't work for free, would you?